# JSON loader with webworker

Tags: three.js, web-worker

How to load Three.js JSON model using webworkers? Main problem I an trying to solve is to make the browser UI responsive by offloading the computations to the webworker.

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/WWOBJLoader2

Comment: This is objloader.I need help with json loader

Comment: I am trying to create a web worker version of json loader in three.js just  like the wwobjloader